# Keycloak automatic login after registration via API

Tags: keycloak

A React SPA sends registration details to a backend (including username and password). Besides other things, the backend creates a keycloak user via the REST admin API.

The user then still needs to go to the keycloak login page for authentication. Is it possible to skip this step and automatically log-in the user on registration via API?

I thought if maybe the backend can obtain a token and send it to the SPA. But I do not know how to initialize `keycloak-js` in this scenario.

Answer (score -1):

You can register the user and, after a successful registration, call the login endpoint with the same credentials in order to receive the access token.

Update:
[image: Sequence diagram of registration flow]

Comment: Could you elaborate how this should set the desired httponly cookies (for sso and also so that user is still logged in after page reload/remember me). I was not able to do it.

Comment: @Stuck I just updated the answer and added a sequence diagram to better explain my solution. In this scenario, the frontend would be the instance to set the cookie not the backend.

Comment: A frontend cannot set httponly cookies.. This also would make the flow insecure. We must let the keycloak server set the auth cookie, I tried implementing a custom spi to extend the keycloak Api, but it sill does not work.

Comment: Okay sorry, I missed the point where you mentioned it should be a httponly cookie. Then you can set the cookie from your backend after the successful login. And everytime you visit your frontend, you call an endpoint at your backend (we like to call it whoAmI) which reads the value of your cookie, gets the user information from Keycloak and returns it to your frontend.

Comment: If our backend sets the cookie, the auth server will not see it on page refresh. It must be set by keycloak.

Comment: @Stuck did you ever discover a solution for this? This is exactly my problem as well.

Comment: @TheHiggsBroson yes, back than we implemented a custom `RealmResourceProvider` for keycloak to provide a new route on the keycloak server that sets the SSO cookie via `AuthenticationManager.createLoginCookie(...)` (see keycloak github repo). We called this endpoint from our SPA after registering the user via our backend. But I would not build it this way again as it is cumbersome to maintain. Rather stick to the standard auth flows and do registration via the keycloak frontend.